# Prove a Little o inequality

Tags: analysis, inequality, asymptotics

I've managed to reduce a proof to the following: I now need to show that $e$$k \choose 2$$(1+f(k))^k<1$ for some $f(k)=o(1)$. I'm thinking the general inequalities $1/e \leq (1-1/(n+1))^n$, or $1/e \geq (1-1/n)^n$ could be useful somehow (e.g. if that $k \choose 2$ factor wasn't there I could just use $f(k)=-1/k$.). But in this case I am not sure what $f(k)$ should be.

Comment: How about $f(k) = -1$ for all $k$?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to type $f(k)=o(1)$. Let me edit this.

Comment: I was suspicious of the $o(k)$. Rearrange and take logarithms, replacing $\binom{k}{2}$ with the larger $k^2/2$ for simplicity. You need $$\log (1 + f(k)) < \frac{1}{k}\bigl(\log 2 - 1 - 2\log k\bigr)\,,$$ so $f(k) = -C\frac{\log k}{k}$ works for $C > 2$ from some $k_0$ on. If you need it to work for all $k \geqslant 2$, check for small $k$ how large a $C$ you need. I'd expect $C = 3$ to work from the start, but that's just a guess without any calculation.